# Problem using AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring

I am using `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` to test my dao implementations.
The above abstract class has a method `exeuteSqlScript` which i am trying to execute before each test case.

So my problem is when i am trying to execute the testcase for saving a record it gives me the below exception `org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Hibernate operation: could not insert`.

Also i dont see any records inserted in the database  with the `executeSqlScript` from the implementation calss of `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.
from the sql script trying to insert few records.

> P.S. i am using spring2.5 and hibernate 3 and mysql.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a transaction manager to your test configuration.

You still may have trouble observing INSERT record changes unless you tell Hibernate to flush the transaction.